# model.predict() output dimensions is not the same as y_train dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I am currently working on an LSTM model to predict the closing price of a stock based on other data. It is my first time working with RNNs. I am using tensorflow.

The issue arises when I try to predict prices over the X train data (which is what the model was trained on). I get different dimensions when compared to the y train data.

I am using 7 features with a timestep of 100 to predict the closing price.

These are the shapes of my input data:

```
x_train = (3697, 100, 7)
y_train = (3697, 1)
x_test = (1584, 100, 7)
y_test = (1584, 1)
```

The input data shape seems correct to me. And I pass input shape of (100, 7) to the model

I then run:

```
predicted_stock_price_train = model.predict(x_train)
predicted_stock_price_train.shape
```

and the output I get is (3697, 100, 1). I was expecting (3697, 1) which is y_train's dimensions.

As a result, while doing an inverse_transform, I get the error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

since fit_transform was passed on y_train.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Edit:
Here's the model.summary() output

```
    Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_15 (LSTM)               (None, 100, 50)           11600     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 50)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_16 (LSTM)               (None, 100, 50)           20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 100, 50)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 100, 1)            51        
=================================================================
Total params: 31,851
Trainable params: 31,851
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: It's better to attach ``model.summary()``'s output to your question.

Comment: After adding flatten layer, you should see the last entry on your model summary is (None, 1)

Comment: @Kaveh Hey, I did what you asked and added a model.add(Flatten()). I got ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_31 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 700).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out what was wrong. Turns out it was a pretty silly mistake.

This was the model that gave the error

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(100, 7)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

What's wrong here is that I have `return_sequences = True` in the last layer before the dense. So the LSTM past on the data and that made the output shape (None, 100, 1)

Here's the new model without the error

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(100, 7)))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

This gives an output shape of (None, 1) and solves the problem.